# grep line that follow a symbol

Tags: grep

How do I grep the line that followes the @ symbol?

I though this should work: grep -A @ file

```
@SRR797059.1 HWIEAS269_0001:5:1:1049:4995 length=38
CGAGCTCCGGCTCGGAGGACCATACTATCGTATGCNGN
+SRR797059.1 HWIEAS269_0001:5:1:1049:4995 length=38
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb^bb]_^aR_]_b_b[_BBBBBBBB
@SRR797059.2 HWIEAS269_0001:5:1:1057:20746 length=38
GGATCTGTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGCTTACTATCGT
```

output

```
  CGAGCTCCGGCTCGGAGGACCATACTATCGTATGCNGN
  GGATCTGTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGCTTACTATCGT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-A` option needs a number after it which would suggest the number of lines you need to print.

From the `man` page:

```
>  -A num, --after-context=num
>              Print num lines of trailing context after each match.
```

So you should try:

```
$ grep -A 1 '@' file 
@SRR797059.1 HWIEAS269_0001:5:1:1049:4995 length=38
CGAGCTCCGGCTCGGAGGACCATACTATCGTATGCNGN
--
@SRR797059.2 HWIEAS269_0001:5:1:1057:20746 length=38
GGATCTGTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGCTTACTATCGT
```

#### Answer for updated question:

```
$ awk 'p;{p=(/@/?1:0)}' file
CGAGCTCCGGCTCGGAGGACCATACTATCGTATGCNGN
GGATCTGTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGCTTACTATCGT
```

Set the flag for the line that contains `@`. Print the next line and disable it.